# Microsoft SQL Server capped 100,000 select

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

Using a python wrapper to query a Microsoft SQL Server database.

The python package name is pyodbc, it uses DB API 2.0.

I create a cursor and `fetchall()` entries from a table that should contain about 120k rows.

It retrieves only 100k rows.

I tried to count(*) from the table, it returns only 100k.
I tried to select * from table except top X, it only returns 100k - X entries

I would expect `fetchall()` to return all entries uncapped since there are `fetchmany()` and `fetchval()` functions

What could be the issue?

---

edit: fixed.

the db copy was capped for some reason. thx @Mark Rotteveel

Comment: If `select count(*) from table` returns 100k, then you can be sure that only 100k rows are in the table (or at least, only 100k rows are visible to your current transaction). The 'problem' is not with Python or pyodbc, but squarely within the database.

Comment: indeed. the person who provided me the data had capped the database copy for some reason and failed to inform so. thx.